# Is there any plugin to make arabic chart (right alignment)?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, charts, highcharts

I couldn't change highcharts align. Is there any plugin to make Arabic chart? I mean that chart should be aligned to right.

Comment: please provide us with some code, a link to your website or a JSfiddle or something.

Comment: It is a general problem, any chart plugin with right align will help

Comment: try https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html

Comment: well this plugin has no much chart types ,no 3d charts and no angular ones and I didn`t find any right aligned chart except 2d bar chart

Comment: What do you mean with right aligned chart? examples? the plugin has angular support though.

Comment: right aligned charts just like that http://imagehost.vendio.com/a/905774/view/DVYBearishAUG2011.png

Comment: You still aren't being specific about what you want. What, specifically, needs to be right-aligned?  You should be able to align pretty much anything in Highcharts pretty much any way you need it...

Comment: I think OP means the axis on the right because he's making an arabic chart and Arabic reads right to left

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have made right-to-left (RTL) charts in Arabic using Highcharts.

This page will be useful:
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/internationalization

There are a few tweaks you need to do:

- Set `opposite: true` on the yAxis to move it to the right side
- Set `reversed: true` on the xAxis to make it flow right to left
- Set `rtl:true` on the Legend to move legend symbols to right of text
- Set `align: left` on the Legend to move legend to the left side (optional)
- Set `useHTML: Highcharts.hasBidiBug` on Legend and all Labels if you intend to support Firefox < 4

You may need other tweaks based on the kind of graph you need (not specified in the question). Also setting `direction:rtl`in your css file can be helpful.

I have modified the Highcharts basic line demo to show these changes (anything marked /* RTL EDIT */ is relevant)

[Highcharts Basic Line](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

[Modified RTL Basic Line](https://jsfiddle.net/qewyxsw6/)